# Unity3D android hiding system software buttons

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have Android devices with version 4.0 and 4.1. Sample Unity3D project hides android system software buttons but at any touch of screen shows them, so to choose something I have to do double-click. My own small project do not hide android system software buttons at all.

I plan to use Unity3D for creating virtual reality apps so fully immersive screen is important as much that I need to understand if Android phone has to have hardware buttons to be used for VR.

Can Unity3D hide software buttons, maybe showing them only by swipe from below?

Comment: Are you talking about the back and menu buttons that on some device are displayed on screen? I don't think that might be an issue strongly tight to unity, maybe the developer can decide to show or hide them in any application, something that can be changed inside the manifest maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

I think Unity might set this:

```
 <activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Inside its default manifest, you then need to override it so that it doesn't tell the activity that contains your viewport to hide the sw buttons.

If I remember correctly in Unity 3 you could just drop AndroidManifest.xml file in the \project\assets\plugins\android\ folder. (Not so sure about it now, things might be different).